# How to generate patch files such that they can be applied from a central location

Tags: git, patch, git-submodules

I am in a situation where I want to include a git project as a submodule in my own project, but also want to apply a few patches using patch files. I also want to automate applying those patch files using a quick setup script that is part of the configuration process.

Is there a "standard" method for doing this? I've generated the patch files but it seems rather complicated to apply them. I was hoping to have a central directory containing all my patch files, and perhaps something like `patch -R` to apply them. From a while of testing it seems patch does not quite work that way, and it would require moving through the directories to apply the patches.

Is there a simpler way to do this or am I using `patch` incorrectly? Assuming I have the following directory structure:

```
root
├── libs
│   └── submodule1
├── patches
    ├── example1.patch
    └── example1.patch
```

How might patch files be generated such that a simple command like `patch -R patches/*` can be run from the `root` directory? Assume that I have the modified code `submodule1_modified` somewhere that I can run patch against to generate the patch files.

I've tried doing this many different ways, but always end up with patch reporting the error `can't find file to patch at input line 4` when I try to apply them. The only way I was able to get this to work was to first `cd` to the root directory of the modified tree and apply there.

Comment: You need a `quilt` tool I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you generate the patch files and what paths are in their headers, but the easiest solution would be to split the patches per project and use `patch -d lib/submoduleN` to apply them in the right directory.

If you want to keep all patches together, you need to either rewrite their headers to include `libs/submoduleN` or simply generate the diffs from the root directory in the first place.

Of course I assume that you patch from the root of the project.